# How to install (automatically) a new document class in Texmaker through MiKTeX?

Tags: installing, miktex, document-classes

I am trying to install a new document class style in Texmaker for a scientific journal. 
There is any direct way to install on Texmaker?

This post discusses [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows), but I want to know if MiKTeX could update (automatically) document class, or is just able to update packages?

Comment: If you have only a `cls` file and only you will use it you can save it in the same folder as your `tex` document. TeX will find it there.

Comment: Probably I am not being clear with my question. I want to know if MikTex is capable of automatically install a document class, using Texmaker. If I got it right you are suggesting to do it manually.

Comment: In the end, class files are just files – same as packages. Yes, MiKTeX can install them 'automatically' and keep them up-to-date (not automatic without some fiddling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The editor (TeXMaker) is irrelevant to the question.

In MiKTeX settings, if you chose "Install missing packages on the fly", it means that MiKTeX will do automatic installation for any file requested during compilation that is in its file name database.

More clearly, if you're running (pdf|xe|lua)(la)tex etc., and the engine tries to load a file that is not on the computer, MiKTeX will check the file name database online. If it finds the file, it suspends the compilation and downloads the package containing that file.

If you type `kpsewhich --help` in the command prompt, it will give you a list of all the file types it handles. (I don't know if automatic package installation works for all of them.)

So **yes**, packages, classes and fonts etc. can be installed on the fly.

You can also install packages from the command line:

```
mpm --verbose --install <package>
```

Comment: I have "Install missing packages on the fly" checked and it normally works all the time, even for classes. However, for this komacv class, something is going haywire. Not only does it not install on the fly, even when I put it in the required directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\komacv and paste the .cls file there, or even in the place where I am writing the file, it keeps saying "File: komacv.cls not found". Any ideas?